# Get variable in file_get_contents('file.php')

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I have a file called file.php with this content:

```
<?php

$foo = 'hello';

?>
<div id="fileContent">
   <?php echo($foo) ?>
  ...some content here
</div>
```

In other file called result.php, I call the file.php with the method file_get_contents():

```
<div id="resultContent">
  <?php echo(file_get_contents('file.php')) ?>
</div>
```

But, I can´t print the internal variable $foo in my result.php file. Only appears as:

```
<!--?php echo($q); ?-->
```

Can I get this result? //print hello in the result.php file

Comment: Use [include()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php). ``file_get_contents`` reads the contents of the file, it does not execute it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

file_get_contents() reads the specified file byte by byte but does not interpret it's contents. What you are searching for is the include() directive:

```
<div id="resultContent">
  <?php include('file.php') ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Oooops, noob error, thanks you. I accept your answer in five minutes ;D

Answer (score 4):

use `include()` instead `file_get_contents()`